# CPU Fair share Server 2016

Tags: citrix, server-server-2016

We have a Citrix farm running Server 2016. CPU Fair Share is enabled (by default) but still we have examples of a single user claiming 100% CPU when running queries in PowerBI.
Shouldn't Fair Share prevent exactly this?

Comment: Why would it, if the CPU is not in use otherwise? And how does the hardware look like?

Comment: You can check there, https://web.archive.org/web/20140213021604/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/05/29/using-wsrm-to-control-rds-dynamic-fair-share-scheduling.aspx, it show some tweaking you can do, but the blog talk about 2008R2, but the information seem hard to find for CPU Fair Share.

Comment: @TomTom The cpu is in use, as there are 8 concurrent connections, so the one user ends up taking all CPU resources when he in my mind shouldn't.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Thanks for the link, but as you said, it's for 2008R2. WSRM has deprecated as of 2012.

Comment: "The cpu is in use, as there are 8 concurrent connections," No. 8 connections does not mean "in use". 7 connections may just watch a static screen at this particular moment.

Comment: @TomTom very valid point indeed, the thing is that the other connected users are not just starring at their screens.

Comment: Interestng enoug hthy may just do that. 8 users it stoo few to statiscialyl have some users ative all the time. Especially when doing data analysis they may all just "think", you know.